# Is this symbol for common-mode choke or usual inductor?

Tags: passive-filter

In the below circuit from [this](http://www.qualtekusa.com/images/EMI_Filters/pdf/84910003.pdf) datasheet, I think L1 represents common-mode choke; but what does L2 represent?

[image]

And in [this](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1523/0900766b81523c26.pdf) datasheet for a similar filter, I don't see any difference between the symbols:

[image]

Which one in these circuits is common-mode choke and which one is usual inductor? Which one has inductance?

Comment: Dot notation is everyone’s friend. Without it the circuits are both ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L1 is a common mode choke. L2 is a single choke but it exist twice in the circuit. If you look at the part designators in the schematic items like C1 and C2 repeat often, obviously as independant parts.

This was done for no other reason then to simplify the parts list. Technically it is NOT the best way to draw up schematics as it is confusing until you understand the intent of showing the same part designator on multiple parts.

EDIT: The L1 symbol defines it as a common mode choke that exist one time only. L2 implies that each instance of L2 has the same value. As @Andyaka noted in his comment irrational self-created notation can make the values per part ambiguous.

The second schematic is more rational to read and it implies that by symbol that both 'L' designators are common mode. To that extent the first and second schematic are NOT the same. The first has ambiguous part values, the second makes thing more clear but does not annotate each part. Company policy may dictate that publicly posted diagrams be a crude approximation of the actual schematic, and not the one they did the board layout with.

Sometimes good engineering is understanding how other engineers think, as they may follow their 'own' standards and not international standards. Must be trying to save on ink...

Comment: Thanks, how about the second datasheet? Both symbols are identical and named as L. Which one is choke? And at page 2 the inductance is given as 0.8mH for the model FN 2060-10. It seems too big for a single choke. Is 0.8mH is for both or only for the CM choke do you think?

Comment: the second data sheet has two identical common mode chokes.

Comment: The L1 symbol defines it as a common mode choke that exist one time only. L2 *implies* that each instance of L2 has the same value. As @Andyaka noted in his comment irrational self-created notation can make the values per part ambiguous.

Comment: So we dont know about the second datasheet whether they are both CM or not?

Comment: I have put some comments into my answer to clarify the ambiguity between 2 schematics with different drawing styles, neither of which has part designators good enough for a board layout program to use.

Answer (score -1):

Both are CM chokes but separated by 2.5 freq decades due to SRF limits and surge pulse current saturation limits of L1 well below 30MHz. The dots are **both on one side**.

They also offer DM filtering attenuation with  C1 and CM attenuation with C2 and in both directions for unintended ingress and egress.  This CM attenuation also serves to attenuate the peak voltage and rise time of lightning surges thus reducing the dielectric stress current and making surge clamps more effective.

C1 is an X cap across the line and C2 is a Y cap to earth with different surge safety ratings.

The two stage approach is often used with L2 being 2 separate chokes and not on a common core depending on the cost/performance advantage of shared cores for CM attenuation vs DM attenuation.